How to play one bit of sound per frame in OpenAL
I have a basic sound scene implemented where I can create arbitrary sounds in arbitrary locations. I also have a sine wave generation function that can create a sine wave data for a given frequency, sample rate, and i (for the corresponding sine result y). I can currently play the entire sine buffer (with size sample_rate * seconds it plays for).
I want to further build this project such that the sound can be played one bit at a time. Meaning, I want to play the first frame of the sine wave, then modify the scene somehow (by either deleting the source or modifying the buffer), and play the second sound frame.
I need this as I need to modify a sound source at runtime. Sound sources may not be heard or have significantly decreased amplitude levels.
I know that deleting the sound buffer and source, then rebuilding them is not desirable due to performance reasons. I have been unable to find working or detailed advice relating to this besides for maybe this or this. I was unable to figure out how the first post could be utilized (I'm not familiar with openAL and could not find much guidance on it), and while the second post was exactly what I was looking for, it seems to be a feature specific to iOS devices.
Edit: I wanted to add some further clarification to this. I create a samples buffer array short samples[sample_rate]. To play a normal sine wave in a loop, I simply have to read the entire buffer into a sound source and play it in a loop. I, however, want to play this sine wave such that it plays samples [0], then in the next frame of the program it plays samples1*0.8 due to some calculation made behind the scenes.

This question makes no sense. A sound frame is typically at least one wave, so something like 20 to 50 ms, depending on the lowest audio frequency you want to support. And even at a meagre 8 kHz sample rate, 16 bits depth, one frame of 20 ms is still 25600 bits. Not "one bit", but many thousands.

title may be misleading. I have an array of sine wave data which is played in a while loop. I simply wish to read the minimum amount of items from the sine data buffer for one pass of the while loop, as I need to do further calculations in the next pass of the loop.

I'm really missing the problem here, TBH. Just don't queue data until you know what you want to queue ?

As I stated in my edit, I want to play samples[0] for one pass of the loop, then play samples[1] with a modified amplitude in the next pass. This process can only happen during each pass of the while loop as there is interaction from the user at every step. My question is on how I can queue sound data to the buffer at runtime.

I've tinkered for alternative solutions and I've gotten a close enough version of it to work. I was mistaken about how the source and buffer items work. I thought that as long as the source was not playing I would be able to modify the buffer associated with it; however I first needed to unlink them (best way is to delete the source but I'd like a more efficient way), load the buffer with new data, and attach the buffer to a new source. While this is a solution, I'm very much open to better alternatives.
